# Any micro-frontend framework that can help to seprerate a old project into modules with which to upgrade Individually?

Tags: frameworks, frontend, upgrade, micro-frontend

Guys have u ever expirenced any micro-frontend framework that cheer you up?

We are sufferring from a huge project using Jquery, having more than 8000 lines code mantained in per page, mannually controlling dom every day.

It's quite difficult to rewirte all of it. Actually I have tried to replace it with webpack and  react, but it is indeed a huge change which will predically bring us under a risk.

In order to split a whole project into serval modules and just make one of these modules upgraded in every release, I am seeking micro frontend framework for help...

Any advices?

Comment: I don't know what is micro for you but what about https://vuejs.org/ or https://svelte.dev/? Both support progressive website enhancement.

Comment: Yeah, vue is good at componentizing.Thanks for your answer thopaw. But I am seeking a framework which not only has component function, but also be able to run with old project. Individually deployed, individually upgraded. Just looks like <micro-service> from backend's prespective.